# Getting options value by java script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

in my old UI design code  i have four options value . its Working correctly i have looks like

```
 <select name="ssmonthlymipfrequency">
            <option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
            <option value="quarterly">Quarterly</option>
            <option value="semianually">Semi Anually</option>
            <option value="anually" selected>Anually</option>
          </select>
```

its Working prefect now i have changed New UI code  four options value change

onclick function its code looks like

```
  <img src="Content/Images/A.png"  style="cursor:pointer" id="A1"  onclick="changeperiod(event,this.id,this.src)" />
                                        </div>
```

i have used script Onclick Function

```
var id;
var eve;
var ImageName;
function changeperiod(event, _id, _src) {
    id = _id;
    eve = event;
    //alert(_id);
    var img = _src.substring(_src.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    ImageName = img;
   $('#mymodal').modal()
    if (ImageName == "A.png") {
        //alert(ImageName);
        $("#anually").prop('checked', true);
        $("#semianually").prop('checked', false);
        $("#quarterly").prop('checked', false);
        $("#monthly").prop('checked', false);
    }
    if (ImageName == "Q.png") {
        //alert(ImageName);
        $("#quarterly").prop('checked', true);
        $("#anually").prop('checked', false);
        $("#semianually").prop('checked', false);
        $("#monthly").prop('checked', false);

    }
    if (ImageName == "S.png") {
        // alert(ImageName);
        $("#semianually").prop('checked', true);
        $("#quarterly").prop('checked', false);
        $("#anually").prop('checked', false);
        $("#monthly").prop('checked', false);

    }
    if (ImageName == "M.png") {
        //alert(ImageName);
        $("#monthly").prop('checked', true);
        $("#semianually").prop('checked', false);
        $("#quarterly").prop('checked', false);
        $("#anually").prop('checked', false);

    }
    // $('#save').hide();
    $('#trigger').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#trigger').addClass('disabledButton');
  }
var value;
$('#myForm input').on('change', function () {
    value = $('input[name="a"]:checked', '#myForm').val();
    $('#trigger').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#trigger').removeClass('disabledButton');
});
$('#trigger').on('click', function () {
    if (value == "A") {
        alert(value);
        $(eve.target).attr("src", "Content/Images/A.png");

    }
    if (value == "S") {
        $(eve.target).attr("src", "Content/Images/S.png");
    }
    if (value == "Q") {
        $(eve.target).attr("src", "Content/Images/Q.png");
    }
    if (value == "M") {
        $(eve.target).attr("src", "Content/Images/M.png");
    }
    $('#mymodal').modal('hide');



});
```

i want pass select name value script function.previous code Working option value. How to pass select name in javascript ? new UI code Not working? 
select name script:

```
 if ($ssmonthlymipfrequency=="yearly")
        {
            $ssmonthlymipamt =$ssmonthlymipamt/12;
        }
        switch($ssmonthlymipfrequency)
        {

         case "anually":
         $ssmonthlymipamtmonthly=$ssmonthlymipamt/12;
         break;
         case "semianually":
         $ssmonthlymipamtmonthly=$ssmonthlymipamt/6;
         break;
         case "quarterly":
         $ssmonthlymipamtmonthly=$ssmonthlymipamt/3;
         break;
         default:
         $ssmonthlymipamtmonthly=$ssmonthlymipamt;
         break;
        }
```

How to pass  select name value in new UI code script ?  thnaks in advance

Comment: What? What is it you want to pass where?

Comment: There is a semicolon missing after `$('#mymodal').modal()`

Comment: My old UI code have options value  now changed options value change onlclick.  select name value pass to my new script

Comment: You're replacing a `<select>` with a bunch of checkboxes?

Comment: Why don't you just use a hidden input, and put `annually`, `quarterly`, etc. in it?

Comment: try this: `$('select[name=ssmonthlymipfrequency]').val('monthly');` - changing the val for the one you want selected - in your case for the one where you set `prop('checked', true)`

Comment: @barmer  previous code have options value in selected name called  ssmonthlymipfrequency .  new UI i have onclick function  with same select name  but i don't know how to pass select name new script of onclick

Comment: So, you want us to make the code for you?

Comment: have tired Not Working expecting idea

Comment: @RajVelN I believe you are confused. Your code looks so odd. Make it simple. On image click, you can easily identify frequency. What is the need of having multiple elements, setting, reading?? On image click itself just do your frequency calculation. If you want to do later then store the frequency value in some hidden field at the time of calculation just get with $("hiddenfieldname").val() in JQuery. Hope it helps.